# Replace Bind event from jQuery with something from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, bookmarklet, unbind

I need to replace the Bind event from JQuery with some event from JavaScript.

I am developing a Bookmarklet and i received order to replace jQuery with JavaScript

I have the following code

```
$(document).unbind("mousemove", X.highlighter);

$(document).bind("mousemove", X.highlighter);
```

and also

```
var current, overlay = $("#overlayhighlight"), o = $('#y');
```

this last 3 I can replace with document.getElementsByID

the bind and unbind ... no clue

Comment: JQuery has great cross-browser support, tell your client that JQuery is more reliable ;-)

Comment: we know, but this is a complex bookmarklet and we should use only js; if a website does not have jquery, the bookmarklet will crack instalntly

Comment: Why don't you then load jQuery in the bookmarklet if it doesn't exist then? You cannot just replace these with javascript, jQuery events include dozens of fixes and features you might be using. Every little thing you have taken for granted must be now coded by you.

Comment: no jquery code is allowed; it could break the website or bookmarklet; i did not know this when i started, but now, jquery must not be used; it's complicated :d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `element.addEventListener()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)) and `element.removeEventListener` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener)).

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', X.highlighter );

document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', X.highlighter );
```

Comment: This is the best suited answer, however, after passing from jq to js, some code, does not respond; i still have : var target = $(event.target),
            offset = target.offset(),
            width = target.outerWidth(),
            height = target.outerHeight(); and this does not respond anymore, because the jq is not there anymore; how do i addapt this code ?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian The listener is getting a `MouseEvent` ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent)) object, that has some information about the event. I'm not sure, but `relatedTarget` could be the property you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.onmousemove(function(){
//do something here
});

var current, overlay = doucment.getElementById("overlayhighlight"), o = docuemnt.getElementById('y');
```

You can replace jquery code by javascript code like above

Comment: i did that part, the document.mousemove is tricky; there are events while using the mouse ... and i now think i know how to use bind undind in js

Comment: i replaced jq with js, and it crashed :)) something is fishy here

Answer (score 2):

### Use the below sample to attach simple events

```
if (document.addEventListener) {  
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', modifyText, false);   
    } else if (document.attachEvent)  {  
      document.attachEvent('onmousemove', modifyText);  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the top of your script and work with jQuery as usual, if a website does not have jquery, doesn't matter.

```
var js = document.createElement("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js");
js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = jsFilePath;
document.body.appendChild(js);
```

Comment: jquery must not be used in this bookmarklet; do you transform jquery in js ? also, i must use my singletone js class, in order to not duplicate any variables, functions ... so ... it's hard

Comment: Some mistakes: `jsFilePath` should be the jQuery URL. It should be `createElement("script")`. You shouldn't access `document.body` as it can be unavailable at the time you run this code. Scripts can also run in the `head`, in which case only the `head` element is available at that time.

Comment: 10x for the help, but we cant use jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onmousemove=X.highlighter;//bind

document.onmousemove=null;//unbind
```

Answer (score 1):

Check our [this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) for lots of mouse event information, more specifcally this one:

> Mousemove
>
> The mousemove event works fine, but you should be aware that it may
>   take quite some system time to process all mousemove events. If the
>   user moves the mouse one pixel, the mousemove event fires. Even when
>   nothing actually happens, long and complicated functions take time and
>   this may affect the usability of the site: everything goes very
>   slowly, especially on old computers.
>
> Therefore it’s best to register an onmousemove event handler only when
>   you need it and to remove it as soon as it’s not needed any more:

```
element.onmousemove = doSomething;
// later
element.onmousemove = null;
```